# dataTables.js breaks after first .click event

Tags: jquery, datatable

Main page:

```
<div id='leftColumn'>
    <input id="showCamsBtn" type="submit" value="Cameras">
    <input id='showRoomBtn' type='submit' value='/*room name populated by SQL query*/'>
</div>

<div id='subPage'>
    <h1> Welcome to the main page!</h1>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( '#showCamsBtn' ).click( function() {
    $( '#subPageHome' ).delay( 0 ).slideUp( 500 , 'swing' ,
        function() {
            $(this).delay( 600 ).load( 'telecameras.php #subPageCam' ,
                function() {
                    $('#camsTable').DataTable( {
                        "info":             false              ,
                        "scrollCollapse":   true               ,
                        "dom":              '<"wrapper"flipt>' ,
                        "pagingType":       "full"     ,
                        dom:                'T<"clear">lfrtip' ,
                        tableTools: {
                            "aButtons" : [ "copy" , "print" ]
                        }
                    } ) ;
                } ).hide().delay( 600 ).slideDown( 2000 , 'linear' ) ;

            } ) ;
        } ) ;
```

**Updated w/ Basic Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/ETHER34L/mts2bcdg/1/

When I click on `#showCamsBtn` a table is loaded from telecameras.php and dataTables (per my above code) is applied perfectly.

However, if I click on one of the rooms buttons in the second list of buttons on the left column, and then click the camera button again, the info from telecamera.php is still loaded okay but without dataTables applied.  If I refresh the page and then click the camera button again then it works.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.  It was a rookie mistake, but an important one.

My IDE had the head section of one of my .load files collapsed so I didn't see that the click event was overwriting my script sources on the main page with ones that were a bit different.  When I changed everything accordingly, the functions started working perfectly.

I also slightly modified my code from

`$( '#showCamsBtn' ).click( function() {`

to

`$( ' #showCamsBtn' ).on( 'click' , function() {`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing an update? Using `fnDraw();` or `fnStandingRedraw()`?

Like:

```
$( '#showCamsBtn' ).click( function() {
    $( '#subPageHome' ).delay( 0 ).slideUp( 500 , 'swing' ,
        function() {
            $(this).delay( 600 ).load( 'telecameras.php #subPageCam' ,
                function() {
                    oTable = $('#camsTable').DataTable( {
                        "info":             false              ,
                        "scrollCollapse":   true               ,
                        "dom":              '<"wrapper"flipt>' ,
                        "pagingType":       "full"     ,
                        dom:                'T<"clear">lfrtip' ,
                        tableTools: {
                            "aButtons" : [ "copy" , "print" ]
                        }
                    } ) ;
                    oTable.fnDraw();
                } ).hide().delay( 600 ).slideDown( 2000 , 'linear' ) ;              
            } ) ;
} ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Fernando.  I tried out your code and it was no joy.  I have called an alert to try and find out when the script breaks.  After a room button is clicked and the page is loaded via jQuery, the buttons in the first section of my left column break.  No alerts no nothing.  However, the data is still loaded, it just drops the function on load complete

Comment: @ETHER34L If I understood. After it is loaded the first time, the buttons do not work anymore? Correct?

Comment: If you check out my fiddle, I have a left column with 2 sets of links.    SET1 (cam and vlan links) SET2 (various room links).  SET1 loads tables as dataTables into `#subPage`.  Now, if I click on any of the links in SET2 before SET1, the tables don't load right.  However, the information is still loaded just without any of the callback functions